# How to add two variables together in sheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make a script that adds the value of one cell to another one before I clear the first cell. Unfortunately, all my attempts to add the second one have given errors. This is my latest one: I get a NUM error here. what do I do?[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHeeh.png)

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example of your code you've tried so far, also followup question, you're trying to add the value of Column A in Column B when you clear value in Column A , right?

Comment: Before I clear A, yes.

Comment: Added sample script as answer please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onEdit` simple trigger, which will give you access to `oldValue` of cell which was edited and you can use that value to add it with column B.

Based on your this problem statement, try this sample script:-

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const row = range.getRow();
  const column = range.getColumn(); 
  var oldValue = e.oldValue; 
  if(column === 1)
  {
    const colB = sheet.getRange(row,column+1); // Getting Column B value
    var colB_Value = colB.getValue();
    oldValue = isNaN(Number(oldValue)) ? 0 : Number(oldValue)
    colB.setValue(oldValue + colB_Value) // adding old value of column A with B and setting it on Column B
  }
}
```

Reference:

[OnEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

[Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

[isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)